# modified CSS3 codes working on IE, but not on Chrome

Tags: eclipse, css, google-chrome, jsp

why does this happen? I'm using eclipse neon.1 and tried changing the color of the font in the CSS3 code and it worked on both internal browser and IE9, but not on chrome. I restarted the server a lot of times and even rebooted the computer but it still won't be applied on Chrome....

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the text and go to inspect element, see if it shows newly applied style in styles section in developer tools. If not you may need to clear cache using Ctrl+Shift+Delete and reload the app.

Comment: Thanx alot it really helped.